# Why different private key strings under Linux or Windows?

Tags: php, openssl, rsa, x509

When I'm creating private key strings with the following PHP code (and same config-parameter), they are enclosed between different strings:

```
$configs = array('config' => 'OpenSSL.cnf',
                 'digest_alg' => 'sha1',
                 'x509_extensions' => 'v3_ca',
                 'req_extensions' => 'v3_req',
                 'private_key_bits' => 2048,
                 'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
                 'encrypt_key' => false,
                 'encrypt_key_cipher' => OPENSSL_CIPHER_3DES);

$privateKeyResourceId = openssl_pkey_new($this->configs);                       
openssl_pkey_export($privateKeyResourceId, $privateKeyString);
```

On Linux the $privateKeyString looks like this:

> -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----NBgkqhkiG9w0BAQE....ASDFasjkfa-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

On Windows the $privateKeyString looks like this:

> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----NBgkqhkiG9E....ASDFasjkfa-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

When I copy the Windows private key string to Linux it works until I remove the 'RSA' from the start/end (same behavior vice versa). Why is this?

Comment: OpenSSL supports more than one private key format. The PEM header identifier which format is being used. The first one is in a standard PKCS format and includes an identifier that indicates that it's an RSA key. The second one is in an RSA-specific format and so doesn't need that identifier. The default format changed between PHP 5.2.9 and 5.3.3.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This would mean that it is not an OS issue. Have to check it out.

Comment: It's definitely not an OS issue. It's a PHP issue. (Neither is broken, it's just that if your code expects one and gets the other, ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a [user note php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-export.php) this is a known issue:

> Please take note that older versions of PHP/OpenSSL exports the RSA private key with '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----' PEM tag, which includes just the privateKey field, thus omitting the version and privateKeyAlgorithm fields.
>
> The effect of that would be that if you're converting it to DER, and
> then back to PEM, but using '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----' PEM tag,
> that the openssl_pkey_get_privatekey() function will fail!Senthryl's
> code can be used to prefix the PEM encoded data with the version and
> privateKeyAlgorithm fields again.
>
> The newer PHP/OpenSSL versions exports the RSA private key with
> '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----' PEM tag, which includes the version and
> privateKeyAlgorithm fields.
>
> I noticed these differences between my two servers:
>
> PHP Version 5.3.3 (OpenSSL 1.0.0a-fips 1 Jun 2010) on Fedora Core 12 x64
>
> PHP Version 5.2.9 (OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007) on Fedora Core 10 x64

Answer (score 11):

This is a differece between openssl versions not PHP. The following openssl command creates different key headers/footers between openssl versions 0.9.x and 1.0.0x:

> > openssl req -new -keyout mykey.key -out mycertreq.csr -nodes -sha1 -newkey rsa:2048

For version 0.9.x, the key header/footer is:

> > -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
> >     -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

For version 1.0.0x, the key header/footer is:

> > -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
> >     -----END PRIVATE KEY-----

For the later version of openssl, I have to run the key file through the following command to make it compatible with the older default:

> > openssl rsa -in mykey.key -text >  mykey.pem

The "mykey.pem" file then has the header/footers (and format) that is **compatible with AWS** and like services.

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problems when trying to upload the key to Amazon AWS!