# Why my private RSA key is not a valid key for Amazon?

Tags: amazon-ec2, openssl

I have generated a CSR and a private key with the following command:

`openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout myserver.key -out myserver.csr`

For the last 3 years I did that I optained a proper private key in the following format:

```
BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY
...
END RSA PRIVATE KEY
```

This format is valid for Amazon and the key was accepted so far.

I had to renew the same certificate so I recreated the key and the CSR on a new EC2 instance with Ubuntu 12.04.

The same command created a private key in the following format:

```
BEGIN PRIVATE KEY
...
END PRIVATE KEY
```

The format is no longer valid for Amazon although the key and the certificate are valid for web servers (Nginx, Tomcat).

So, why the behavior has changed ? Do I have to generate a private key with an older version of OpenSSL or an option is available ?

Comment: When you say: "The format is no longer valid for Amazon", how did you come to that conclusion? What error message do you get?

Comment: The official documentation specifies the format for accepted certificate and keys: See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_UpdatingLoadBalancerSSL.html

Comment: Ok I see now. The last answer to this question suggests a way to convert the file, maybe you can try that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678202/why-different-private-key-strings-under-linux-or-windows

Answer (score 3):

Run the following to convert the key into an AWS compatible format

`openssl rsa -in myserver.key > myserver.key.pem`